# Assigning parent keys in innermost object using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I would like to turn this:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

into this

```
[
{"a": 1, "b": 1},
{"a": 1, "b": 2},
...
]
```

This is sort of like python's `zip` but with unequally shaped objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this works: `jq '.a as $a| .b[] | {"a": $a,  "b": .} '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
$ jq -Mc '[.b=.b[]]' data.json
```

If `data.json` contains the sample data the output is

```
[{"a":1,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3},{"a":1,"b":4}]
```

Comment: I like how this answer would work if there are other attributes than "a" in the outermost level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat ab.json|jq '[{"a": .a, "b": .b[]}]'` to get the answer.

Comment: for some reason i grok this answer better than the others.

Answer (score 1):

If minimizing keystrokes is the goal, then consider:

```
jq '.+{b:.b[]}' <<< "$j"
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 3
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 4
}
```

Using `.` here ensures that all keys other than "b" will be preserved. By contrast, if one wants to ignore all the keys other than "a" and "b", then one could use the jq filter:

```
 {a,b:.b[]}
```

To turn the stream into an array, just wrap the expression in square brackets: [ ... ]